# Cloning GitHub repo into IntelliJ IDEA java classes

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

I work from two different laptops and naturally use GitHub VCS to link the my work among the machines. I recently started a Java project where the `.class` files are saved in the `src/` directory.

Whenever I clone the remote repo into my 2nd machine none of the classes will run. I have the proper SDK/JDK assigned and setup.

here is the error message:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/me/idea-IC-141.1532.4/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/home/me/idea-IC-141.1532.4/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain HourglassFigure
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HourglassFigure
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I suspect the `.iml` files is to blame? or is it also because I am using .gitignore?

Whenever I create a new IDEA project and merely copy the code into a new java class file the code executes without flaws.

Comment: As a rule class files are throw away files that are not stored with a project in a VCS, distributed or otherwise.  The only way the ignore file can be to blame is if you are also want to store your project (iml) file in git and the ignore file is telling git to ignore the iml.  I would check in the project structure (F4) to see if the directory with the class files is being added to the class path.  That said I wouldn't push class files to git.

Comment: How do Java programmers using IJ IDEA conveniently commit & clone repositories? I removed the `.gitignore` setting preventing `/out/` and `.class` commits yet I am still unable to conveniently share my work

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I don't check in IDE settings because they may vary between machines (like JDKs may be in different locations, IDE-specific executables may be at different paths etc.). This is the IntelliJ/sbt-related excerpt of my .gitignore:

```
target/
.project
.idea*
/project.plugins/project
ca.log
*.iml
```

So add that to your .gitignore, set up the project on both machines and see if it works.